# Generate debug.keystore without building (only have .apk)

Tags: android, web

I have a **project** made with **HTML**, **CSS**, **JS**, working well on **desktop**. It uses authentification on Google (OAuth) in order to use Google API, it connects on Google Drive.

Now i want to have my application on **Android** (With phonegap builder i can create the .apk.)

So i created a Google Account (**Google Console API**) and i chose:

- Installed Application
- Android

And then i need to generate the **certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint** but i don't have the **debug.keystore** file because i can't generate it by building the project (obviously it is a HTML, CSS, JS project so **i can't compile it**).

I searched for generate the debug.keystore with Eclipse **but** my project is not an Android project (i tried to convert its nature but it doesn't work), so i don't know how to generate it.

**In conclusion**: i need to generate the debug.keystore of my project in order to authentify my project on Google with the certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint.

Regards

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639275/android-keytool-error-on-the-command-line-when-locating-debug-keystore/4222461#4222461

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [how to](http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.in/2012/12/first-phonegap-app-with-android-using.html) might be of help. After creating the project, replace the html, css, js with your code, Make sure you have linked them well. Then from eclipse, right click the project and select android tools > export signed application project. In next step create a keystore with a password. After that you can save the apk and you will have a local keystore file.

Also while registering your Application to get Client id., make sure that you select Installed Application and Android.

Comment: Thanks dude! the .apk created with your tutorial works but when i try to connect to google drive it says: "Invalid Parameter value for origin: Missing Authority: file://".
(I created the google client ID and entered the certificate's SHA-1 fingerprint so i think it's ok, it recognized the client_id)

Do you have an idea?

Comment: (in my application i connect to Google Drive in order to use Google API, with OAuth 2.0 system)

Comment: "Also while registering your Application to get Client id., make sure that you select Installed Application and Android."

Yes i selected Installed Application and Android