# Google map in android by using keytool

Tags: android, api, google-maps, keytool

I am going type the below command to get the information of keytool

```
keytool -list -v -keystore “C:\Users\key\.android\debug.keystore” -alias androiddebugkey -   storepass android -keypass android
```

however, it said my key file is not exist.

```
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.doCommands(KeyTool.java:738)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.run(KeyTool.java:340)
    at sun.security.tools.KeyTool.main(KeyTool.java:333)
```

Btw I am using key in my user name, I dont know it is related or not.
Please help me if You know what happen. Thanks.

I have used the highest premission to run cmd but it is the same result.

Here are the snap shot about the path of keytool and androiddebugkey

http://postimg.org/image/xew43joon/
http://postimg.org/image/hwbrj0d5h/

Comment: Which operating system you are using  ?

Comment: then I think the path `C:\Users\key\.android\debug.keystore` is not proper path, there should be a username in that path. First of all open your c:\ and check where is your debug.keystore file is and the n put that path in this syntax.

Comment: 'key' is my username in my computer.

Comment: Yes. I checked. It is there which in the same path

Comment: As I read from above (not sure if it is a copy & paste issue), the double quote used is incorrect, and it should be `-storepass` (remove those space)

Comment: @user3423149, Yes I agree with Raptor, `-   storepass` this should not contain any space, it should be `-storepass` like this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: keytool error on the command line when locating debug.keystore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2639275/android-keytool-error-on-the-command-line-when-locating-debug-keystore)

Comment: I guess it is a copy and paste problem. I have double check there is no space there.

Comment: post your snapshot where your debug.keystore file exist. i will create it for you.

Comment: Hi @i.n.e.f Do you mean I need to run the problem before going keytool? But I have to say I have not complete the application.

Comment: I have taken the snapshot and post it in the main content. Thanks.

Comment: in your first snapshot window follow steps of my answer.In First snapshot window press `ctrl+shift+right click` you will get `option open command window here` open that no need of writing whole path & then just copy past this line of code `keytool -list -v keystore debug.keystore` & press enter you will require password put `android` as password & that's it all done.

Comment: hope you will get it what i am saying :)

Comment: I am sorry I just finished of my dinner
I will try it now thanks

Comment: @i.n.e.f 
I have tried but I dont think there is key tool in that folder
So It appear an error to show that keytool is not a correct command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Simple.Try replacing your double quotes “ and ” with ". They are different in command prompt.

Comment: I think i got that mirror mistake. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

i have one more solution to this problem. Simple press Ctrl+shift+Right Click you will get option **Open command window here** open Command Window . Do all this where your  debug.keystore file exist & paste this line **keytool -list -v keystore debug.keystore** and it will ask for password Enter **android** as default Password. Imean to say follow this steps You will surely get rid of your problem.Its working From myside.Hope this will solve your problem.